# PHP_RELEASE_VERSION on PHP7 shows 6 instead of 7

Tags: php

Is there any logical explanation for `PHP_RELEASE_VERSION` constant  showing `6` instead of `7` on **PHP7**?
Is this related to the *jump* from version `5` to `7`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have installed PHP version 7.0.**6**?

You are probably confusing it with [`PHP_MAJOR_VERSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: Long night yesterday... Thank you for the explanation.